# Pattern for getting from multiple repositories

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have several objects that implement an interface, and several repositories that perform CRUD operations these objects.

I'm given a GUID and I don't know which class the object is, but it's in one of them, and am using the repository to get the object by its GUID.

The repos return different types.

```
class Obj1 : IInterface
{
}
class Obj2 : IInterface
{
}
class Obj3 : IInterface
{
}


var repo1 = new Repo1();
var repo2 = new Repo2();
var repo3 = new Repo3();

Obj1 obj = repo1.Get(someGuid);
if (obj != null) 
{ 
    // use obj
}
else 
{
     Obj2 obj2 = repo2.Get(someGuid);
     if (obj2 != null) 
     { 
         // use obj2
     }
     else 
     {
         Obj3 obj3 = repo3.Get(someGuid); 
         if (obj3 != null) 
         { 
             // use obj3
         }
         else 
         {
             // Check another repository
         }
     }
}
```

This gets more tedious as more objects implement that interface.

Is there a pattern for this or a nicer way of doing it?

Comment: I have to wonder if a better 'if block' really helps you. Maybe there is a way you can know which repo to check

Comment: Pretending objects can be stored in a database never ends well regardless of what API you put in front of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V2 answer, based on extra info supplied.

Since `Repo1`, `Repo2` etc all have a `Get` that returns an `IInterface`, then you can use `Func` delegates and linq to simplify this:

```
var repo1 = new Repo1();
var repo2 = new Repo2();
var repo3 = new Repo3();

var repoGetters = new List<Func<GUID, IInterface>>
{
    repo1.Get,
    repo2.Get,
    repo3.Get
};

var obj = repoGetters.First(func => func(someGuid) != null);
```

`obj` will then be of type `IInterface`.

The above assumes a match is guaranteed. If not, replace `First` with `FirstOrDefault` and test `obj` for `null` to see if a match occurred.

Comment: That would've been a good answer but they don't implement a common interface :(

Comment: @Graham, Do the `Gets` return a common type?

Comment: No the objects returned are different types but the objects implement the same interface

Comment: @Graham, answer updated therefore to provide a solution.